# proving bi-Lipschitz function has an inverse that is lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing, metric-spaces, inverse-function-theorem

How could I go about proving that a bi-Lipschitz function has an inverse that is a Lipschitz function.

Definition 1: bi-Lipschitz function. Given metric spaces $(X,d_X)$, $(Y,d_Y)$, a function $f:X \to Y$

is called bi-Lipschitz if there exists a constant $K>0$ such that for all $x_1,x_2 \in X$, we  have  that

$$\frac{1}{K} d_X(x_1,x_2)\leq d_Y(f(x_1),f(x_2))\leq K d_X(x_1,x_2)$$

Definition 2: Lipschitz function. Given metric spaces $(X,d_X)$, $(Y,d_Y)$, a function 
$f:X \to Y$
 is called Lipschitz if there exists a constant $K>0$ such that for all $x_1,x_2 \in X$, we  have  that

$$d_Y(f(x_1),f(x_2))\leq K d_X(x_1,x_2)$$

Comment: Start writing the definition of "bi-Lipschitz function".

Comment: Use \to in things like $f:X\to Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that since $f$ is Lipschitz, then $Kd_x(x_1,x_2) \geq d_y(f(x_1),f(x_2))$, therefore, $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \iff x_1 = x_2$, so $f$ is one-to-one. Now, let $f^{-1}$ be the inverse map of $f$ mapping $f(X)$ one-to-one onto $X$.

Hence, for all $y_1,y_2 \in f(X)$, there is a unique $x_1,x_2 \in X$ such that $f^{-1}(y_1) = x_1$ and $f^{-1}(y_2) = x_2$. Now we can just substitute in the original equation:
$$\frac{1}{k}d_x(x_1,x_2) \leq d_y(f(x_1),f(x_2)) \leq K d_x(x_1,x_2)$$
We get:
$$\frac{1}{k}d_x(f^{-1}(y_1),f^{-1}(y_2)) \leq d_y(y_1,y_2)$$
And,
$$d_y(y_1,y_2) \leq K d_x(f^{-1}(y_1),f^{-1}(y_2))$$

So the inverse is also bi-Lipschitz.

Comment: for the conclusion do you mean to say it is also lipschitz?

Comment: Well, it is Lipschitz, but we can actually prove a stronger claim that it is bi-Lipschitz.

Comment: This proof is based on the proof in the book Lectures on Real Analysis by Yeh. He proves the inverse is actually bi-Lipschitz.

Comment: consequently I understand the proof. it proves the inverse of a bi-lipschitz function is lipschitz and also bi-lipschitz?

Comment: Yes, it proves it is bi-Lipschitz, which is Lipschitz.

Comment: Why is a Lipschitz function invertible? $\vert x \vert$ is Lipschitz but not invertible/one-to-one? What am I missing here?